# How to insert a condition when defines a function

Tags: python, function, curve-fitting

I have a function that contains 3 distributions. It's supposed that the sum of the 3 distributions is one.

First, I simulate 3 sets of data and make their respective histogram to graph independently:

```
s1 = np.random.lognormal(2.0, 0.4, size = (20000, 1))
s2 = np.random.lognormal(1.2, 0.2, size = (20000, 1))
s3 = np.random.lognormal(1.5, 0.4, size = (20000, 1))

mb = np.max([s1,s2,s3])
X = np.arange(1,mb,0.1)
 #histogram population 1
Y11, bins1 = np.histogram(s1, X)
Y1 = Y11/Y11.sum()
X1 = bins1[:-1]

 #histogram population 2
Y22, bins2 = np.histogram(s2, X)
Y2 = Y22/Y22.sum()
X2 = bins2[:-1]

 #histogram population 3
Y33, bins3 = np.histogram(s3, X)
Y3 = Y33/Y33.sum()
X3 = bins3[:-1]
```

Then, I concatenate the 3 sets of data into one and make a histogram to work on it:

```
 #all mixed populations
S =  np.concatenate((s1, s2, s3), axis=0)
Yi, bins = np.histogram(S, X)
Y = Yi/Yi.sum() #Data is normalized to have and area under curve of 1
X = bins[:-1]
```

I define a function that describes the 3 distributions (Sorry for my ugly code):

```
def logN(x, mu1, mu2, mu3, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, P1, P2, P3 ):
    P1 = 1 - P2 -P3 #Here I define that the sum of three fractions is one
      
    return  P1*(np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu1)**2 / (2 * sigma1 **2)) / (x * sigma1 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))+ P2*(np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu2)**2 / (2 * sigma2 **2)) / (x * sigma2 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))+ P3*(np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu3)**2 / (2 * sigma3 **2)) / (x * sigma3 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))#lognormal function

params, pcov = curve_fit(logN, X,Y, method="trf", bounds=((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),(2, 2, 2, np.inf, np.inf,np.inf,1,1,1)), p0=(1,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.3,0.3), maxfev=4000)
print(params)
```

The function seems to be working (at least graphically):

```
x = numpy.arange(0, mb, 0.1)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))  #size of graph
plt.plot(X1, Y1, 'o', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(X2, Y2, 'o', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(X3, Y3, 'o', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot(X, Y, 'r', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(X, logN(X ,params[0], params[1],params[2], params[3], params[4], params[5], params[6], params[7], params[8]),'b', linewidth=2) 
plt.xlim([-5, mb+5])
plt.ylim([0, 0.08])
```

[image]

But the problem comes when I see the fraction of each distribution (that is supposed that the sum must be 1):

```
params[8]+params[7]+params[6]
Out[155]: 0.4285989056828722
```

It just seems that the function is ignoring my condition `P1 = 1 - P2 -P3` Someone can help me what is wrong with my approach.

Comment: It's a little strange because you reassign `P1 = 1 - P2 -P3`, so your `P1` argument of `logN` is actually thrown away immediately. It seems like you shouldn't have `P1` as an independent parameter in your model at all. What are the fraction values for `params[8] # P3`, `params[7] #P2`, `params[6] #P1`?

Comment: they are low `params[8]+params[7]+params[6]
Out[173]: 0.3917180359992062`
`params[8]: 0.035952721047110094
params[7]: 0.06437618598815326
params[6]: 0.29138912896394287`

Comment: Note that `params[6]` has barely budged from the initial value of 0.3 you set in `p0`. I think that is happening because `logN` throws it away immediately every time, so it barely factored into your model at all. The real P1 in `logN` is actually stored in your P2 and P3 parameters.

Comment: is there a way to constrain something like`P1+P2+P3=1`?

Comment: Look at this another way. Your model `logN` actually uses arguments P2 and P3 as independent parameters and assigns `1-P2-P3` to P1 as a dependent parameter. It just so happens that `logN` has an unused argument that is also named P1, an imposter P1. Now, you're asking if we can constrain the imposter P1 to the real parameter P1, but I say why even keep the imposter P1 around? Remove it entirely, and the real P1 is simply calculable from P2 and P3.

Comment: It has sense but I don't understand how to make it works

Comment: I'll edit parts of your code in an answer to plainly show you what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your code would look like if you omitted the unused imposter P1:

```
# unused argument P1 is gone, the real P1 in the function still there
def logN(x, mu1, mu2, mu3, sigma1, sigma2, sigma3, P2, P3 ):
    P1 = 1 - P2 -P3 #Here I define that the sum of three fractions is one
      
    return  P1*(np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu1)**2 / (2 * sigma1 **2)) / (x * sigma1 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))+ P2*(np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu2)**2 / (2 * sigma2 **2)) / (x * sigma2 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))+ P3*(np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu3)**2 / (2 * sigma3 **2)) / (x * sigma3 * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))#lognormal function

# You have one less parameter to fit
params, pcov = curve_fit(logN, X,Y, method="trf",
                         bounds=((0, 0, 0, 0,      0,     0,     0,  0),
                                 (2, 2, 2, np.inf, np.inf,np.inf,1,  1)),
                         p0=     (1, 1, 1, 0.5,    0.5,   0.5,   0.3,0.3),
                         maxfev=4000)

# yada plota yada

# *params in function call is simpler way to write params[0], params[1],...,params[7]
plt.plot(X, logN(X , *params),'b', linewidth=2) 

# if you want to know the real P1
P2 = params[6]
P3 = params[7]
P1 = 1-P2-P3
```

Try it out, it should still work just like before.

Comment: I see your point, that's a nice way to skip the problem!